# How to get updated state from redux store inside a normal function in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have been using `react` and `redux toolkit` recently. I just came across a strange issue.

I have a react component `ChatUI` inside of which there is a normal `javascript` function `nextQue`

**`nextQue Function`** 
It has a `post` API call and the response is then dispatched to reducers to update the `messages`
state.

I want the latest messages array inside `mailTime` function as I have to post them. Knowing that `useSelector` is synchronous and is does give me latest `messages` array. but, I am not able to get the latest `messages` inside `mailTime` function if I `log` the `messages` inside and outside the `mailTime` function I am getting the desired data outside the function but ***not*** inside the function

Here, is the code for a look (you don't have to answer based on the following code you can talk globally about what can be a solution to these kind of problems.)

```js
const ChatUI = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const messages = useSelector((state) => state.msg.messages);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const mailTime = () => {
    // const requestOptions = {
    //   method: "POST",
    //   headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    //   body: JSON.stringify({
    //     data: messages,
    //   }),
    // };

    // fetch(
    //   "https://api-url",
    //   requestOptions
    // )
    //   .then((res) => res.json())
    //   .then((data) => {
    //     console.log("datdat", data);
    //   });
    console.log("not latest", messages); //not getting the desired length
  };

 console.log("latest messages", messages); //getting the desired length

  const nextQue = (message) => {
    setLoading(true);
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: {details to be posted}
    };

    fetch(
      "https://api-url",
      requestOptions
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("data...", data?.data[0]?.question);
        dispatch(
          msgActions.add({
            meta_value: data?.data[0]?.question,
            post_id: data?.data[0]?.id,
            type: "bot",
          })
        );
   
        if (!data?.data[0]?.id) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            setLoading(false);
            console.log("messa", messages);
            mailTime();
          }, 1000);
        }
      });
  };
return <></>
}
```

So I know what's happening over here but It would be great if I get response for any solution or hints. Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Comment: try sending messages as parameter

Comment: I also tried it but still the same issue persists

Comment: that's not possible, If you are sending as parameter, it will be updated state only

Comment: As I said It's still is not working

Comment: When you dispatch the action, the next render will have the updated state. The problem in your code is that you are calling the mailTime() function inside setTimeout and when the state is updated and renders the component, mailTime have the old `messages` value due to closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access to store directly from mailTime function you can achieve that using `const store = useStore()` inside your component and then inside mailTime function call `store.getState()` to access state but I don't think that it's a best solution.If you need to do some chained api request i will suggest you to move that part to middleware.